# Reading variables by another thread - variables won't change

Tags: c#, multithreading, variables

So I have a problem here. I declare some variable in my class, then I try to change it and then read it with my windows form thread. The variable is being read as the initial value that it was declared with, and nothing can change it. Example:

I declare the value in my Class1.cs:

```
public static int TestVar = 51;
```

Then I change the value later in that same class to for example 45:

```
TestVar = 45;
```

Then I read the variable from my windows form thread like this:

```
label1.Text = Class1.TestVar.ToString();
```

And the result in my windows form is 51 instead of 45. It doesn't matter if I declare it to 0 or without any initial value. It will just stay as 0 instead.

The class it has been declared it reads the variable fine as 45, somehow the other thread doesn't have it updated.

The windows form is being run using:

```
public void RunThread()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunForm));
    thread.Name = "NewForm";
    thread.Start();
}

public void RunForm()
{
    Application.Run(new NewForm());
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you add working sample for the problem?

Comment: You'll need to post more code.  I'll put a dollar on "you also have a local variable named TestVar".

Comment: Sorry, this problem is part of a bigger application. And no, I don't have a local variable. I tried it with completely new variables to begin with. Interestingly enough, when I display the windows form using the thread where the variable was declared, it works fine. When I launch it from yet different thread - its back to initial state.

Comment: Maybe you got it declared as ThreadStatic. You want us to guess?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Yeah - you have to debug it.  Is 'TestVar = 45;' actually being executed?  If you change the name, eg. 'public static int TestVar2 = 51;', what errors are thrown by compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the variable in several threads, you have to declare it `volatile`:

```
public static volatile int TestVar = 51;
```

Comment: Tried that. Same result.

Comment: And you are sure the change happens before the variable is read?

Comment: Yes. I set it, then read it in same class and its changed fine. Then when I display the form, its shown in it's initial state, I can open the window or set the variable to something else countless times, it won't update it.

Comment: @FrozenHaxor You have a bug in the parts you haven't show us. Can you post a small, self-contained, complete test case showing the problem. I am sure while you prepare that code you'll find the bug...

Comment: I just don't get it, how there can be any bug if the variables aren't used any elsewhere

Comment: @FrozenHaxor Simple. You wouldn't ask this question if there weren't :) I repeat, how about posting a simple, self-contained case showing the problem (code not words)?

Comment: As I'm not really experienced in programming, I'm not sure if I can accurately reproduce the problem, I'll give it a try though.

Comment: @FrozenHaxor Yes.. this is the start to debug your problem and best way to learn something.